# How to generate an action address from another controller?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have an action in a controller that placed in an area.

> www.site.com/Panel/Product/GetProduct

in this url, "Panel" is area name,"Product" is controller name and "GetProduct" is action name.

In this **method** I created a link to another action in diffrent controller and area.

> www.site.com/Home/Index

I used this code to generate url:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home",null, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

but resulted url is like this:

> www.site.com/Panel/Home/Index

in case desired controller is outside area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont want to use this code in view. I cant use this code in action.

then try this code;

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Area = "" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below.

```
Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "AreaName" }, new{})
```

Comment: I don't think that the last parameter has to be `new`-ed. null should be fine

Comment: I dont want to use this code in view. I cant use this code in action.

Comment: This is wrong. As question stated "Creating an action address from controller" not View